# View file isn't completely displayed- Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a form using ruby on rails. However my code only shows the content in the  tag and the rest of the content is not displayed. My code is as follows

Controller:
user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def register
@title = "Signup"
end
end
```

View:
register.html

```
`<h1>SignUp</h1>
<% form_for :user do |f| %>
<fieldset>
<legend>Sigup</legend>
<label for="name">name:</label> 
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<br />
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<br />
<label for="password">Password: </label>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<br />
<%= submit_tag "Signup", :class => "submit" %>
</fieldset> 
<% end %>   
`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `=`:

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
```

`form_for` is a method which returns a string. `<% %>` just executes the code, `<%= %>` will insert returned value to html.

Comment: It worked. That was one of the dumbest mistake I was unable to figure out! Thank you! I appreciate it.